# Moment JavaScript - get differences between two date

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I'm trying to get date differences between the today date and a destination date in moment.js, here what I have do:

```
var now = moment().format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss');
var then = moment("15/09/2017 14:20:30").format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss');
//here i try the difference
var diffTime = moment.utc(moment(now).diff(moment(then)));

console.log("differenza per countdown "+diffTime);
```

The console.log return me "Invalid date" but if I use now as "then" it return me 0 (which is correct), how can I create a properly formatting data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your date format is not a standard one, in that case specify it explicitly as second parameter or parsing will fail in different browsers.

```
moment("15/09/2017 14:20:30", 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss')
```

Ans yes, there is no value in converting to string and parsing it back to date unless you have some other logic in between.

```js
window.onload = function(){
var now = moment().format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss');
var then = moment("15/09/2017 14:20:30", 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss').format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss');
//here i try the difference
var diffTime = moment.utc(moment(now, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss').diff(moment(then, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss')));

console.log("differenza per countdown "+diffTime);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

For me the result is `NaN` but date parsing can differ with browsers.

```js
window.onload = function(){
var now = moment().format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss');
var then = moment("15/09/2017 14:20:30").format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss');
//here i try the difference
var diffTime = moment.utc(moment(now).diff(moment(then)));

console.log("differenza per countdown "+diffTime);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: seems legit, but why return negative num?

Comment: Negative Number? `NaN` is Not a Number if you are referring to that.

Comment: For me the result is NaN but date parsing can differ with browsers, you can add breakpoints and inspect the values in each step.

Answer (score 4):

Why are you formatting the moment to a string just to parse it again thereafter? There's no point in doing this.

Use moment.duration on the difference:

```js
var now = moment();
var then = moment("15/09/2017 14:20:30", "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss");
//here i try the difference
var diffTime = moment.duration(then.diff(now));

console.log("differenza per countdown "+diffTime);
console.log("humanized: " + diffTime.humanize(true));

console.log(diffTime.days() + "/" + diffTime.months() + "/" + diffTime.years() + " " + diffTime.hours() + ":" + diffTime.minutes() + ":" + diffTime.seconds());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: cool! but one last thing, hte humanized return me 7 days, but if i want the difference in DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss format?

Comment: I'm not sure how you would display a difference in this format. If you want to have the days, months, years, ... as a difference, you can show that instead of using humanize. I've added something, maybe this is what you need @PdsInk

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `Date.parse()` to convert dates to milliseconds, and then find the difference.